# iPhone page curl transition animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to instigate a page curl transition with a `UIImageView` in a Window. This code is in my main init method :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animCompleteHandler:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:splashImage cache:YES];

splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 10, 10);
//[splashImage removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The image animates position and size but no curl. If I uncomment the `removeFromSuperView` it just vanishes instantly. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Have changed the code so it uses Lars fantasticlly neat way of triggering an animation and including the animation and callback ...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                      delay:delay
                    options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                 animations:^{splashImage.alpha = 0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[splashImage removeFromSuperview];}
 ];
```

Unfortunately the page curl just doesn't happen. It does fade though.

I'm not sure if this is something to do with the syntax or the fact that the `SplashImage` is a `UIImageView` class in the `UIWindow` object of my main view. Maybe it needs to be in a `UIView` to create the transition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:splashImage 
        duration:1.5 
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
        animations^{
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 10, 10);
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [splashImage removeFromSuperview];
            //animCompleteHandlerCode..
        }
];
```

Not tested and maybe some syntax errors but give it a try!

Or maybe this is better:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
        delay:delay
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
        animations^{
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 10, 10);
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [splashImage removeFromSuperview];
             //animCompleteHandlerCode..
        }
];
```

Comment: I've not tried this yet but I'm intrigued by your code! What does the ^ do? Is this a way of embedding functions?

Comment: Those are blocks new to iOS 4.0.
I encourage you to read up on blocks. Great addition to iOS. Check out this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html

If i understand your code correctly what you want to do is curl a page and at the same time move and scale it?

Comment: well the moving and scaling is not really important ... I just wanted to trigger the transition. Was using that transformation just to test it was working. I just need the splash image to page curl away. To trigger this as a transition I need to do something to the view. Would it work with 'hidden'? Anyway, I'm running some tests now. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yeah probably.. Just pass in nil instead of the animation block.. And set the splashImage to hidden or alpha to 0.0.. After or before the transition method..

Comment: In case this is not known, there is a : missing after the word "animations". It should be: animations:^{

Answer (score 1):

@Larsaronen: Thanks for the examples, it was exactly what I needed!  I just wanted a simple page curl while images are first displayed, so I used an alpha of 1.0 instead of 0, and set the completion callback to nil:

```
// set a page curl animation for the specified UIImageView control
- (void) setAnimationPageCurl:(UIImageView *)imageView {

    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView 
                      duration:1.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown 
                    animations:^ { imageView.alpha = 1.0; } 
                    completion:nil];
}
```